# Replacing text in gsub by evaluating a backreference

Tags: r, regex, gsub, backreference

Let's say i have some text :

```
myF <- "lag.variable.1+1"
```

I would like to get for all similar expressions the following result : `lag.variable.2` (that is replacing 1+1 by the actual sum

The following doesn't seem to work, it appears that the backreference doesnt carry through in the eval(parse() bit ):

```
myF<-gsub("(\\.\\w+)\\.([0-9]+\\+[0-9]+)", 
            paste0( "\\1." ,eval(parse(text ="\\2"))) ,
            myF )
```

Any tips on how to achieve the desired result ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can use *your current pattern* with `gsubfn`:

```r
library(gsubfn)
x <- " lag.variable0.3 * lag.variable1.1+1 + 9892"
p <- "(\\.\\w+)\\.([0-9]+\\+[0-9]+)"
gsubfn(p, function(n,m) paste0(n, ".", eval(parse(text = m))), x)
# => [1] " lag.variable0.3 * lag.variable1.2 + 9892"
```

Note the match is passed to the callable in this case where Group 1 is assigned to `n` variable and Group 2 is assigned to `m`. The return is a concatenation of Group 1, `.` and `eval`ed Group 2 contents.

Note you may simplify the callable part using a PCRE regex (add `perl=TRUE` argument) `\K`, match reset operator that discards all text matched so far:

```r
p <- "\\.\\w+\\.\\K(\\d+\\+\\d+)"
gsubfn(p, ~ eval(parse(text = z)), x, perl=TRUE)
[1] " lag.variable0.3 * lag.variable1.2 + 9892"
```

You may further enhance the pattern to support other operands by replacing `\\+` with `[-+/*]` and if you need to support numbers with fractional parts, replace `[0-9]+` with `\\d*\\.?\\d+`:

```r
p <- "(\\.\\w+)\\.(\\d*\\.?\\d+[-+/*]\\d*\\.?\\d+)"
## or a PCRE regex:
p <- "\\.\\w+\\.\\K(\\d*\\.?\\d+[-+/*]\\d*\\.?\\d+)"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
gsubfn("(\\d+\\+\\d+)", ~ eval(parse(text = x)), myF)
#[1] "lag.variable.2"

 gsubfn("\\.([0-9]+\\+[0-9]+)", ~ paste0(".", eval(parse(text = x))), myF2)
#[1] "lag.variable0.3 * lag.variable1.2 + 9892"
```

---

Or with `str_replace`

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(myF, "(\\d+\\+\\d+)", function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
#[1] "lag.variable.2"
```

---

Or an option with `strsplit` and `paste`

```
v1 <- strsplit(myF, "\\.(?=\\d)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
paste(v1[1], eval(parse(text = v1[2])), sep=".")
#[1] "lag.variable.2"
```

#### data

```
myF <- "lag.variable.1+1"
myF2 <- "lag.variable0.3 * lag.variable1.1+1 + 9892"
```

Comment: Thanks ! these do work for when the character string is isolated like the in the example. But what if the expression is part of a longer string like " lag.variable.3 * lag.variable.1.1 + 9892"

Comment: @satellite42 also it is not clear which one you want to add and whether you need multiplication as well?

Comment: @satellite42 what is the expected output for the string you commented

Comment: My bad, the second example was a bad copy-paste. For correction, I have formulas like second example (" lag.variable0.3 * lag.variable1.1+1 + 9892"), I need it to become `" lag.variable0.3 * lag.variable1.2 + 9892"` . Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @satellite42 updated the post with `gsubfn`